# Are there any php frameworks contain small webserver and rich console tools like RoR/Django?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django

In Ruby on Rails, I can start my web application, just write in console: script/server.
RoR contains small webserver and rich console tools, but I didn`t meet such tools in php frameworks. 
Are there any php frameworks contain small webserver and rich console tools?

Answer (score 2):

Neither PHP, nor any of the PHP frameworks bring their own webserver. Some frameworks offer `rake` like tools like Cake's `bake` or ZF's `Zend_Tool`. There is also [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) and [Pake](http://github.com/indeyets/pake) that are not specific to a framework. The closest to Gem in PHP is [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/). You can start PHP in interactive mode from the shell with `php -a`

As of PHP 5.4 PHP also has it's own internal werbserver, which you can start from CLI with

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

You can read more about that feature at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is the closest. Your models/views/controllers directories will be the same. All of the concepts like routes, active record, plugins, and scaffolding are similar. The active record implementation supports associated models (one-to-many, many-to-many, etc). This is something that is lacking in other php ORM implementations.

Here's an old (April 2007) Ask Metafilter that had some folks contributing frameworks to look at: CakePHP, Symfony, Mojavi, Code Igniter are the PHP MVC frameworks recommended. They suggested CI and Symfony over Cake.