# do I need to setup a server in my computer in order to debug PHP code using Zend debugger ?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

I have Eclipse PDT and Zend debugger installed and I want to test my php code before uploading it into a remote server. My code needs to read some values in the remote files I don't know how configure PHP debugger in Eclipse for that case. Then I tried to test it locally but I think I have to setup a server in my computer, am I right?. By the way, Eclipse offers me to create servers by downloading server adapters, and there are several options. I'm really confused. What do you think about [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef) for debugging php ? is it a quick solution?

Comment: For the server part, look at something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html‎) to get up and running quickly on   your local machine.

Comment: if you juste want to check for parse error, you can run php in the terminal with you php file like $php index.php

Comment: @NicolasManzini if he just wants to check for parse errors, he can run php from the command line with the `-l` flag to lint the file without executing it.

Comment: @Gordon I didn't know that flag, that's cool thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to test my php code before uploading it into a remote server

In order to *test* your code, you write [Automated Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automated%20testing%20php). That way you don't need to verify manually each time you change something. See [unit, integration and system tests for PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984096/unit-integration-and-system-tests-for-php-applications)

> Then I tried to test it locally but I think I have to setup a server in my computer, am I right?

No. [Zend Debugger allows you to step your local code](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/working_with_the_debugger.htm). And you can also execute the code by just [running the script and check it's output](http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Studio-7/running_php_scripts_locally.htm). However, if you want to [test by clicking through your application's UI](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/working_with_the_debugger.htm#MiniTOCBookMark4), then you need a webserver. PHP has a built-in webserver though, which might be sufficient for that purpose. See [Are there any php frameworks contain small webserver and rich console tools like RoR/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246904/are-there-any-php-frameworks-contain-small-webserver-and-rich-console-tools-like/3247128#3247128)

On a side note, [Eclipse with PDT and Zend Debugger is not Zend Studio.](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison) If you want to use Zend Studio with a local server, consider installing [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition) which will setup the entire PHP stack for you for out of the box usage. [No fiddling with getting Zend Debugger running with XAMP.](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=5903) Questions about Zend Studio and Server are best asked at http://forums.zend.com btw

Comment: well, I think I have much info to be read. I will try your suggestions and see what I get. Thanks.